# Characterization of elementary arithmetic operators to explain certain properties in programming languages

Tags: arithmetic, binary-operations

In the LISP-like family of programming languages, the four elementary arithmetic operators behave differently:

`+` and `*` can take any number (including 0) of operands, and perform successive additions/multiplications of the operands, starting from 0 or 1 (the identity of the operation) in order to accomodate the case with 0 operands,

`-` and `/` behave similarly, but they must have at least an argument, and in this case they computes the inverse and reciprocal of the argument, otherwise perform successive subtractions/divions of the arguments.

So:

```
(+) -> 0
(+ 2) -> 2
(+ 1 2 3) -> 6
(*) -> 1
(* 3) -> 3
(* 1 2 3) -> 6
(-) -> error
(- 3) -> -3
(- 3 2 1) -> 0
(/) -> error
(/ 2) -> 1/2
(/ 8 2 2) -> 2
```

So, this is the question:

Is there a way of characterizing mathematically this difference among the four operators `+`, `*`, `-`, `/` ? Or better, is this different behaviour justified on mathematical basis? Or you think it is somewhat an arbitrary decision of the designers of those programming languages?

Comment: This is more a case of operator overloading than anything else, I would say. There are plenty of other examples of “unary minus” and “binary minus” operators coexisting in a programming language. The “unary /” in Lisp is likely a convenient parallel to unary minus.

Comment: @amd : note that if what Renzo wrote is correct, in LISP $(-\  5) \to 5$ and not $-5$ ! hence to get the number $-5$ from the non-negative integers you'd need $(- \ \ 0\ \  5)$

Comment: @ Renzo : you know that historically, LISP was written in the very early ages of programming, and I suspect the $-$ and $/$ operations have chosen such that the LISP parser/compiler is as simple as possible. clearly, $(/\ \ 4\ \ 2) = 2$ so it is logical that $(-\ \ 4\ \ 2) = 2$ too. many years after, $+,*,-,/$ became $n$-ary operators instead of $2$-ary, and logically (for backward compatibility) it became what you wrote.

Comment: @user1952009, sorry, I made a mistake, tha value of `(- 5)` is `-5`.

Comment: + and * are associative and commutative; - and / are not.

Comment: @awkward Lisp treats all of these arithmetic operators uniformly as left-associative.

Comment: It might be worth noting that while `(- a b c ...)` is equivalent to `(reduce #'- '(a b c ...))`, `(- a)` is not equivalent to `(reduce #'- '(a))`. The unary versions of - and / represent different operations than their n-ary counterparts.